# C++ Mutable Mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have multi threading program with enable state and queue concurently, so i will use mutex method like bellow

```
{std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_en(eventLogMutex);en = enable;}
```

my question, should i use different mutex lock guard for enable and queue, like

```
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_queue(eventLogMutex);
  ....
}
```

and

```
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_en(eventLogMutex);
  ...
}
```

Thank's

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should. A `lock_guard` relies on RAII to lock and unlock the mutex - when it goes out of scope, the mutex is automatically released. If you make the `lock_guard` a member variable, using it will be pointless. You should define the `lock_guard` in a scope as closest to the protected code as possible - initialize it right before you actually need the lock, and have it go out of scope right after you're done with the mutex.